# How can I adjust the distance between captions and subcaptions using subfloat?

Tags: floats, subfloats

For the following code I get the result in the image. How can I adjust the distance between the image and its captions ?

[image: code output]

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\subfloat[Sinal na $f_c$.]{
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
   0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figuras/v_va.eps}
 \end{minipage}}
\hfill  
\subfloat[Sinal DC na entrada]{
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
   0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figuras/v_iA.eps}
\end{minipage}}
 \caption{Resultados obtidos.}
\label{fig:exp_pa2}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You can replace your images with `example-image-a` or `example-image-b` for testing (they are integrated in latex distributions).

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

Remove `[1\width]`.

#### Longer answer

With `\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{0.5\textwidth}...\end{minipage}` you're asking that the minipage is as high as wide and this is the cause of the issue. And you don't need `minipage`.

You're also adding unwanted spaces, by the way. Look at the `%` characters protecting endlines in the second `figure` of the following code, which compares what happens with your code and my suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Some text above

\begin{figure}[htp]
\subfloat[Sinal na $f_c$.]{
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
   0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \end{minipage}}
\hfill  
\subfloat[Sinal DC na entrada]{
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
   0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{Resultados obtidos.}
\label{fig:exp_pa2}
\end{figure}

Some text in the middle

\begin{figure}[htp]
\subfloat[Sinal na $f_c$.]{%
  \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  }%
}% 
\subfloat[Sinal DC na entrada]{%
  \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
  }%
}
\caption{Resultados obtidos.}
\label{fig:exp_pa2-right}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that you also get white space above the subfloats. Just for completeness, here's a picture of the same where a frame is added around the `minipage`s in your code, where you see that they are square.

[image]